# ViewPager with Indicator in listview

Tags: java, android, listview, viewpagerindicator

Is it possible have indicators in `ListView`? I know we can do the same with `ViewPager` but I am unable to do the same for `ListView`. How can I implement the following:

[image: ![enter image description here]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use this library: `https://github.com/ongakuer/CircleIndicator`

It is very simple. In the XML:

```
<me.relex.circleindicator.CircleIndicator
        android:id="@+id/indicator"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="48dp"/>
```

In the java class:

```
ViewPager viewpager = (ViewPager) view.findViewById(R.id.viewpager);
CircleIndicator indicator = (CircleIndicator) view.findViewById(R.id.indicator);
viewpager.setAdapter(mPageAdapter);
indicator.setViewPager(viewpager);
```

Comment: your xml is only for indicator or in it is include and viewpager.. or I need put view pagerand your example?